# Badge count inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

There appears to be a discrepancy between the badges displayed next to my username and the badges displayed on [my profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135618/nathan-taylor).

At the top of the page on M.SO I see 2(S) 13(B) (total:15), but on my profile page there are only 13 badges listed.

Similarly, on SO I see 14(S) 31(B) (total:45), but on my profile page it lists 46.

[image: Profile Page]
[image: Meta Flair]

Comment: There, I fixed that question for you. Now I can upvote ;-)

Comment: My theory is that this is a side effect of the talkative badge.

Comment: @waffles that perfectly explains what I am seeing on my end, but doesn't explain what Nathan is seeing.

Comment: This has been fixed *going forward* and the currently affected users will have badge counts synced later tonight.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Thanks- that is a definite improvement. @waffles I had a feeling it might be related to the 'talkative' badge. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @waffles +1 I'm experiencing the exact same thing, and it only started when I was awarded the Talkative badge.

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing a similar issue:

[image: 1+4+18=23]

[image: 23!=24]

Comment: 23, hmm? Now if that isn't one for Welbog's conspiracy theories...

Answer (score 0):

Same here when I received silver Sportsmanship badge.

[image]