# Badge count on profile page should reflect true count, not unique count

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

I have 21 badges on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

[image]

My profile shows I only have 19:

[image]

It's obviously not considering the fact that I have more than one of a certain badge ([Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus) and [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2278/custodian)). Tags are handled in a similar way. That is, by only counting unique entries:

[image]

However, the connotation between a total tag count is different between that and a total badge count, as the former is not displayed with your profile summary next to posts.

My suggestion would be to present a cumulative count for the badges on the profile page or perhaps include a distinction between unique and total badge counts.

Unrelated questions that all reference an inconsistency based on a different matter:

- [Wrong Badge Count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69451/168244)
- [Badge count inconsistency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71402/168244)
- [Badge count is incorrect on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123715/168244)

Comment: Perhaps it could say "21 badges (19 unique)" or something like that.

Comment: When I get another [insert badge name here], I want to see the number go up. :-)

Comment: Imagine what Skeet thinks! EEK!

Comment: It could also separate between normal and tag badges.

Answer (score 7):

I think your proposition is wrong from a UX standpoint.  When I'm about to browse through 4 pages of badges, say @ 20 per page, I want to know the total number I'm going to go through.  I don't want to finish thinking, "then where are the other 200?"  When that particular badge count is displayed, the number of unique badges is far and wide the question of more interest to the surrounding information displayed.

I wouldn't mind more precise language though, but I think given the language in question, this is the correct trade-off.